# Neo4j Query to Table Problems

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My problem is I put data into Neo4j from what was essentially a large spreadsheet essentially. Now I want to be able to get that data back out in a similar tabular format.

Lets say I have some notional spreadsheet of data that went in looked something like the following.

```
| Artist | Album | Song | Live | Filename | Genre | Year | Source | Label | 
|--------|-------|------|------|----------|-------|------|--------|-------|
| ....   | ..... | .... | .... | ........ | ..... | .... | ...... | ..... |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The spreadsheet was a listing of files with some metadata about each file. For analytic purposes it made more sense to not have the file be at the center of the graph but rather the Albums. So that every record in the table above would map to a handful of nodes and relationships. The data model for this might look something like this:

```
(Song)-[_IS_ON_]->(Album)
(Artist)-[_SINGS_]->(Song)
(Album)-[IS_IN_]->(Genre)
(Song)-[_IS_IN_]->(Genre)
(Album)-[_IS_]->(Live)
(Album)-[_FROM_]-(Year)
(Album)-[_IS_ON_]->(Source)
(Label)-[_PRODUCED_]->(Album)
```

I am able to query a single record from my spreadsheet above using a query similar to this.

```
MATCH (a:Album {name: "Hells Bells"})-[r]-(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s:Song)<-[_SINGS_]-(aa:Artist)
RETURN *
```

I have two questions here.

1. How do I make the above query return a table that looks similar to the original normalized table? If I did `RETURN b.filename, b.genre ...` I get a table that has a lot of `null` values. It would seem I need to do a `DISTINCT` on each of the fields. But I am still really new to Neo4j and am not positive I understand how to do this.
2. It would be great if there was a way to get all the fields in all the nodes without having to type them out in the query like this `RETURN b.filename, b.genre ...`. I think I figured this out once but I stupidly didn't save it.

I hope this was clear enough. I can't share my graph model or data so I had to make this up on the fly.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

1. Try the following (but, since you did not state how to get the filename, that value might be missing):

   ```
   MATCH
     (artist:Artist)-[:_SINGS_]->(song:Song)-[:_IS_ON_]->(album:Album {name: "Hells Bells"})-[:_FROM_]-(year:Year),
     (album)-[:_IS_IN_]->(genre:Genre),
     (album)-[:_IS_]->(live:Live),
     (album)-[:_IS_ON_]->(source:Source),
     (label:Label)-[:_PRODUCED_]->(album)
   RETURN *
   ```
2. In a `RETURN` clause, if you specified a node/relationship (without a property name), that would generate a map of all its properties. The above query, for example, would return a map for each matched node.

   If you actually want to have a single merged map, you can use the APOC function [apoc.map.mergeList](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#map-functions). For example:

   ```
   MATCH
     (artist:Artist)-[:_SINGS_]->(song:Song)-[:_IS_ON_]->(album:Album {name: "Hells Bells"})-[:_FROM_]-(year:Year),
     (album)-[:_IS_IN_]->(genre:Genre),
     (album)-[:_IS_]->(live:Live),
     (album)-[:_IS_ON_]->(source:Source),
     (label:Label)-[:_PRODUCED_]->(album)
   RETURN apoc.map.mergeList([artist,song,year,genre,live,source,label,album]) AS result
   ```